# GACUtil "Assembly successfully added to the cache" but "Number of items = 0"

Tags: gac, gacutil

Why, when I run:

```
gacutil –i  myAssembly.dll
```

do I get:

```
Assembly successfully added to the cache
```

But then when I run:

```
gacutil –l  myAssembly.dll
```

I get

```
Number of items = 0
```

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try with

```
gacutil –l  myAssembly
```

donot add .dll at last.So if the dll is registered in GAC it will display

```
Number of items = 1
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Silly reason, really, but it took me what felt like hours to fix and is not really something you want to have to deal with when you’re in the middle of trying to figure out a complex problem.

To add the assembly to the GAC you need to specify the .dll extension, but when trying to query it or unregister it you must  **NOT** specify the .dll extension.

Running

```
gacutil –l  myAssembly
```

will return

```
Number of items = 1
```