# GACUtil “Assembly successfully removed from the cache” but “Number of items =1”

Tags: com, gac

I ran

```
gacutil /u Assembly
```

I got:

```
Number of items uninstalled = 1
```

But then I ran:

```
gacutil /l Assembly
```

and got:

```
Number of items = 1
```

Note that I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393981/gacutil-assembly-successfully-added-to-the-cache-but-number-of-items-0), which seems like a reverse case, but I have not included  '.dll' and yet I still have this problem. Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I puzzled for a while how the displayed number of items could go negative.  Accuracy matters, you are not helping us help you.

Comment: Nice one (below the belt) Hans Passant. The hyphen was meant to be equals. It have now updated it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

All I had to do is delete the contents of the download cache and restart the machine. So this works

```
gacutil /u Assembly
gacutil /cdl
```

Then restart the system